# Set Athena Query result location different for different workgroup

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I created different workgroups and databases for different customers into Athena. I want to set different Query result location with different workgroup now. But whenever I am changing the Query result location for one workgroup other workgroup locations are changing as well.

Is there any way to save different Query result location for different workgroups?

Expecting the procedure to set different Query result location for different workgroups and database into Athena

Comment: In what way are you changing the query result location, CF/Terraform, CLI or console? Either way, please provide additional information on the steps you've taken or code/template blocks which you've used. I've tried to replicate your issue in the console, but it worked as expected (one workgroup query location output changes, not all).

Comment: @ms12 I create separate DBs & WGs for different customers from my AWS user. Steps are:

1. Created two S3 buckets for each customer (Source & Target bucket)
2. Uploaded CSV files in a schedule into Source bucket
3. Created separate workgroup & database for each customer in Athena
4. Assigned query result-set location as Target Bucket of that specific customer into Athena Query Editor (Setting->Manage->Query result location and encryption)
6. Now when I am changing the workgroup & database from one customer to another from Athena, the "Query result location and encryption" is not changing